# Convert atom timestamp with timezone in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, strtotime

I have some json data which contains timestamps in atom format.
Some examples of timestamps:
2020-04-12T04:05:08.92949232Z
2020-03-24T22:59:13.447142853+01:00

I'm trying to convert these with 'date("Y-m-d g:i:s",strtotime($atom)' but It seems to have problems with the +timezone format.
It works fine with $atom = "2020-04-12T04:05:08.92949232Z".
But if $atom = "2020-03-24T22:59:13.447142853+01:00" I get 1970-01-01 12:00:00.

I've played around with DateTime::createFromFormat but I just cant get it to work.
Is this possible to parse without to much effort or do I have to shoot the guy creating the json files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime causes problems if there are more than 6 digits after the period.
You must limit the digits to a maximum of 6 after the decimal point, then the expressions will be accepted.

```
$strDate = '2020-03-24T22:59:13.447142853+01:00';

//reduce microseconds to a maximum of 6
$strDate = preg_replace_callback('~\.\d{7,}~',function($match){
      return ltrim(sprintf('%0.6F',$match[0]),'0');
},$strDate);


$d = date_create($strDate);
var_dump($d);
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-03-24 22:59:13.447143" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+01:00" }
```